# accessing/handling wireless keboard input(key press) in my ipad application

Tags: iphone

i have already done much googling on this neither i found a tutorial/way to accomplish this nor find that it could not be acheived(so that i can assist my client ,it's not possible) we have requirement to integrate a wireless keyboard in our existing ipad application. some of the scenarios are.... suppose you are having a uibutton on the view. then according to the requirement if user tap the key "entr/return" on the wireless keyboard the result is same as tapping the button on view.if user tap the key "i" on the wireless keyboard the result is same as tapping the information button (UIButtonTypeInfoDark) on view.

Means we have to handl wireless keyboard key press events.

any idea/link/tutorial would very helpful for this situation. thanks!

Comment: I'm missing how this is a UX question

Comment: This is more of a programmatic question. Flagging to be moved.

Comment: @user340334 i have already posted this question on stackoverflow but with no answers thats why i tried very first time on UX, sorry for the inconvenience, still if some one can answer me??i have got nothing the whole day r&d and searching on google.hope some can give me a direction..

Answer (score 2):

```
// Use the keyboard (<UIKeyInput>) class and provide for the delegates 
// required by this class
// Put the <UIKeyInput> at the end of the @interface line in the header file.
// Then make sure these methods are in your class as they are delegates 
// for the UIKeyInput class:

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder 
{
    return YES;
}
- (void) deleteBackward 
{

}

- (void) insertText:(NSString *)theText 
{

    theText = [theText capitalizedString];  // Ignore case
    const char *keyPressed = [theText UTF8String];
    switch(keyPressed[0])
    {
        case 'A':   // Do something associated with the 'A' key
            break;
        case '4':   // Do something associated with the '4' key
            break;
            // etc.
    }
}

- (BOOL) hasText 
{
    return YES;
}

-(void) endUserInput 
{

}
```